# The Answer Exists - Cryptography

Tags: cipher

I have a nice riddle for you.
It involves cryptography.

> At last, he thought.
>   We're finally out of this town.
>   "New town, new beginnings" said to himself.
>   Row after row, they passed through the seats
>   in the plane, and took theirs. Mastered.
>   When they got to the new house, they were amazed.
>   What they didn't know is that
>   The house was haunted.
>   Word spread quickly of the new family in
>   town. People warned them about the ghost,
>   so they called the local Ghostkickers
>   and they took the ghost.
>   Years later, a code was hidden inside
>   the ghost. A very important code.
>   "After 200 years," said the ghost "We're finally free! Run my ghosts Run!"
>   
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 192|4 |_ 5 _|
>   Beginning String:
>   JrphHREfhVDvnFRxi2Zs3QeF7ipgAz3kI6cmzNb2ly8=
>   
>   Related Riddle: (Necessary)
>   "Unrelated, Start to End, Row will give the answer."
>   
>   Check final answer with this string:
>   P5XuU/uqmtI1JZ8+oGG4SSexk2aw7wv1E3ORhppJ3J1JsOhyHFaEvAzFRi0BL2Fh0H9f5+2GvhdA>FFzIE556d90huneHJdONAkQSDHV3GWwVJGZcLNKn7rffXkpRlJqw

Comment: Is the incorrect spelling of exists a clue or an error? Oh it's also your username.

Comment: yes, sorry about that... english is not my native

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is AES?

THE first one goes to 287278416 with the key that is in quotes, the second one is NOT base-64, but can be split into 2 base64 strings.

The first of the 2 decrypts to: 4222261970, and the 2nd one is: 2658826205.

that > symbol must mean that 4222261970>2658826205, right?

Now what?

Answer (score 1):

A small bit but perhaps useful.  In the "necessary riddle",

> the capital letters are **USER**, which could then make the whole thing into "USER will give the answer".
>
>  The OP's user number is 28520, if that helps.